# Conversion Failed Converting varchar to Int - using Concat

Tags: sql-server-2012, type-conversion, concatenation

I'm attempting to concatenate two fields into one, the first one is a varchar and the second is an int. I'm getting a "conversion failed when converting the data type varchar to data type int" error, and I'm not familiar enough with sql to troubleshoot on my own why this is happening.

The code is as follows:

concat(polpolicynumber, '-', convert(varchar(10),poltermsequence)) as RefValue

I'm also not sure why it's attempting to convert it to an int. Keeping it as a varchar is what I want.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Thanks so much!

Here's the entire code in case that helps:

```
declare @rundate date = '10-02-2015'
select @rundate as RunDate, 'FINYS' as Source, 'Agency' as ReferenceTable, 'AgcID' as RefID, agcid as RefValue, 
agcname as LastName, '' as MiddleName, '' as FirstName
from COHPROD_Policy..agency
where AgcExpirationDate is NULL or agcexpirationdate > @rundate
union
select @rundate as RunDate, 'FINYS' as Source, 'Agent' as ReferenceTable, 'AgtID' as RefID, agtid as RefValue, 
agtname as LastName, '' as MiddleName, '' as FirstName
from COHPROD_Policy..agent
where AgtTerminationDate is NULL or AgtTerminationDate > @rundate
union
select @rundate as RunDate, 'FINYS' as Source, 'Policy' as ReferenceTable, 'PolNumber' as RefID, 
concat(polpolicynumber, ' ', 'Term', ' ', convert(nvarchar(10),poltermsequence)) as RefValue, 
isnull(connamelast,'') as LastName, isnull(connamemiddle,'') as MiddleName, isnull(connamefirst,'') as FirstName
from COHPROD_Policy..policy p
join COHPROD_Policy..ContactXref cox on coxpolid = polid
join COHPROD_Policy..Contact con on conid = coxconid
join cohprod_policy..policystatus on pospolid = polid
where pospolicystatus = 'active'
```

Comment: Are you sure that `polpolicynumber` it's a `VARCHAR`?

Comment: Yeah. Weird, right? Just checked again when you asked that. It says:

Column PolPolicyNumber(varchar, null)

Comment: Is that all your code?

Comment: No. I'll edit the main post with the entire code.

Answer (score 2):

The error doesn't seem to be from the `concat`, but when you use `union` there. You have `agcid as RefValue` in the first query (which I assume is an `INT`), `agtid as RefValue` in the second query (which I also assume is an `INT`).

And then you have `concat(polpolicynumber, ' ', 'Term', ' ', convert(nvarchar(10),poltermsequence)) as RefValue` in the last query, which is clearly a `VARCHAR` and can't be `UNION`ed directly with the previous columns.

Comment: Ahh okay. So I should convert the agcid and agtid (which you are correct, are ints) to varchars first? Would that solve the issue?

Comment: @RJames why don't you try and see? ;-) (but, yes, that should solve the issue)

Comment: Ha. :) Thanks. Done and done. Issue resolved. Much appreciated, Lamak!